# escribir en fichero con php a través de un formulario

Tags: php, fopen

estoy trabajando el crear y modificar un archivo desde php.
Lo que quiero es, a través de un formulario escribir tres números en un fichero. Luego necesito mostrar por pantalla el resultado de sumar esos números que están en el archivo.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="uno"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="dos"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="tres"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>


  </body>
</html>
```

Como seria el código php. utilizando fopen, fwrite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proba de la siguiente forma:
Si te sirve cambia los valores que yo seteo por defecto en $uno, $dos, $tres por $post['uno'], $post['dos'], $post['tres']

```
            <?php

            $uno = 2;
            $dos = 3;
            $tres = 4;

            // Abro el archivo

            $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");

            // Le cargo los datos

            fwrite($file, $uno . PHP_EOL);

            fwrite($file, $dos . PHP_EOL);

            fwrite($file, $tres . PHP_EOL);

            // Lo cierro

            fclose($file);

            // Lo abro para leerlo

            $fileOpen = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

            // Creo un array para meter los datos convertidos a Int ya que vienen como String

            $datos = [];

            // Voy leyendo el archivo y voy metiendo los datos en el array

            while(!feof($fileOpen)) {

            $dato = fgets($fileOpen);
            echo $dato. "<br />";

            array_push($datos, (int)$dato);

            }

            // Sumo los Int del array y muestro el total

            echo "Este es el total: ".array_sum($datos);

            fclose($fileOpen);

            ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]